# Is my code creating a deep or shallow copy of my object?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, deep-copy

I have this code which takes a stack made up of a external pointer and internal pointers with linked lists, I can't tell if it's making a deep or shallow copy though. If I don't have enough information I'm sorry, I think this is what you need to tell though. Thank you!

```
void StackClass::operator =(const StackClass& orig)
{
    //stack = nullptr;
    node* temp = orig.stack;
    if (!orig.IsEmpty())
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            stack = orig.stack;    // sets thew new stack equal to the old stack's value
            temp = temp->next;
        } // end while loop
    } // end if
    else
    {
        stack = nullptr;          // sets it to an empty list because there's no values
    } // end else
}
```

Comment: If `stack` is just a pointer then all it does is copy the pointer.

Comment: @JonathanPotter it is just a pointer, so then i'm not making a deep copy i would assume

Comment: The code's a complete mess.  For a start, it needs to `delete` any existing elements in the `*this` object's stack before trying to copy anything from `orig`....  To deep-copy, there would have to be some call to `new` (even if indirectly by calling some other function that `new`s) - clearly this code doesn't do anything like that, if `stack` is indeed a `node*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's just copying the pointer i.e shallow copy is in effect.

Deep copy means rather than just copying pointer you explicitly allocate memory for your new pointer and store the contents of passed in pointer into that which your code happens to be missing...

Comment: So I must then copy all of my values at each linked list data and put it into the new one?

Comment: My stack is made up of struct which has one piece with "data" and the other is a node* next which gets you to the next value in the list. the pointer stack points at the top of the stack